# How to pass data to shared views in ASP MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am new to ASP MVC. What I am trying to do is to pass data from database to layout view of the application.

I have a layout for my application in which there is a side bar. It contains the title of the latest news/notices posted. I want the list to be available to all the pages of the application. The side bar is visible in all the pages. I have achieved this by defining a separate independent view(i.e a view without a controller).

All the pages of the application inherit this view. I have used "RenderBody" method in the layout. Now, as the layout do not have any controller, how can I pass the data from database to this shared _Layout.cshtml page.

Comment: How large is data? what about using Session/ViewBag/TempData?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could code a controller base class to handle situations like this. Then use Html.Action in layout to request the news data. This way, you could extend or change the notices in every controller by overriding the action.

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    public virtual ActionResult News()
    {
        return PartialView("_MyPartial");
    }
}

public class HomeController : BaseController
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

And somewhere in your _Layout.cshtml:

```
@Html.Action("News")
```

That being said, I don't see anything wrong with coding an independent controller for shared actions, ie. SharedController.

Answer (score 1):

In your _Layout you could use something like:

```
<div id="sidebar">@Html.Action("Index", "Sidebar")</div>
```

In the (new) SidebarController:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var data = db.News.Get(); // Get database data
    return PartialView("_Sidebar", data);
}
```

And a partial view called _Sidebar in the Shared folder to display the news items.

Comment: Now if I used a sidebarcontroller, then wouldn't it be possible that a route is made. If I type sidebar in my URL then wouldn't it throw some errors....

Comment: I do not understand your point. What do you mean by a route is made? That it is also reachable from the URL? You could use an Action attribute like [ChildActionOnly] to ensure it can only be called as a child action (to prevent a user request)

Comment: Sorry that I am unclear, exactly I mean to say that. Thank you for pointing that out....now I figured it out....